# Any way to get a centered caption over a colored background in the \subfloat[] environnement?

Tags: subfloats

I have compilation errors when trying to set changes in the caption format. I want to modify sometimes (not for all the captions) its background color. With `colorbox`, the centering is lost. When using `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, compilation fails. Is it due to fragile/robustness of commands (these notions are slightly new to me, since I usually use TeX to write maths)? Is there a way to have colored background and centered text with `\subfloat[]` (only for a couple of them, not systematically)?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{5pt}{5pt}
\begin{adjustbox}{center, scale=1}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=6.0cm,height=6.0cm]{my_image.jpg}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=6.0cm,height=6.0cm]{my_image.jpg}}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you in two-column?

Comment: No. What is the meaning of TeX SX ?

Comment: I see no caption, no color and no change to the caption format.

Comment: It's  simply my abbreviation for ‘TeX LaTeX Stackexchange’. Why do you use the figure* environment then? It"s made to have full width figures in two column mode.

Comment: The caption texts (between the brackets) were removed - they are not relevant. I use the subfloat environnement because I want the graphics side by side.

Comment: @marmot, <br> For instance, I'm trying to do white / centered text in a green box for the 1st picture subcaption, and black / centered text in a yellow box for the 2nd picture subcaption.

Comment: @cis: did you try \colorbox? I mean
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.85,1}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Murmel.eps}}
\caption{\colorbox{shadecolor}{ It's hibernation time!}}
\end{document}

Answer (score 2):

I may not interpret the question correctly. However, I cannot reproduce the statement that \colorbox does not work. :

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{framed}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{changepage}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \newcommand{\white}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}
 \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.3,0.85,0.3}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure*}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{5pt}{5pt}
    \begin{adjustbox}{center, scale=1}
      \subfloat[\colorbox{shadecolor}{\white{It's time to hibernate!}}]{\includegraphics[width=6.0cm,height=6.0cm]{Murmel.eps}}
      \subfloat[\colorbox{shadecolor}{\white{It's time to hibernate!}}]{\includegraphics[width=6.0cm,height=6.0cm]{Murmel.eps}}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yet, this is not exactly what I'm trying to get. More like :  
\includegraphics[width=6.0cm,height=6.0cm]{image.jpg}  
\caption*{\colorbox{green}{\parbox{\dimexpr\captionwidth-2\fboxsep}{\begin{center} {my_caption_text} \end{center}}}  
as in <a href="http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=802447KWGO.jpg"><img src="http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_802447KWGO.jpg" alt="Heberger image" /></a>.

Comment: @ncis: seems like you found a way to color the pics, and the captions can be colored as in the examples. This seems to solve the problem (?)
For some figures (vector graphics I guess) it is possible to color them in TeX with e.g. \begin{shaded}\includegraphics{vectorgraphics.eps}\end{shaded}, but for pixel graphics this does not seem to work.

Comment: Nay, the example (for the subcaption) was photoshop'ed. I still don't know how to TeXified it.

Comment: @ncis: but in the example there is a TeX code, and the captions are centered (???)

Comment: It works with \caption{} (that is the case of a single image), not inside a \subplot[] (i.e. several pictures). A compilation error occurs due to the \begin{center} ... \end{center} environnement.